# Unix - How do I have my shell script process more than one file from the command line?

Tags: shell, unix, for-loop

I'm trying to modify an existing script I have to take up to three text files and transform them. Currently the script will only transform the text from one file. Here's the existing script I have:

```
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]
     then 
      if [ -f $1 ]
       then
    name="My Name"
    echo $name
    date
    starting_data=$1
    sed '/^id/ d' $starting_data > raw_data3
    sed 's/-//g' raw_data3 > raw_data4
    cut -f1 -d, raw_data4 > cutfile1.col1
    cut -f2 -d, raw_data4 > cutfile1.col2
    cut -f3 -d, raw_data4 > cutfile1.col3
    sed 's/$/:/' cutfile1.col2 > last
    sed 's/^ //' last > last2
    sed 's/^ //' cutfile1.col3 > first
    paste -d\ first last2 cutfile1.col1 > final
     cat final
      else
    echo "$1 cannot be found."
    fi
    else
    echo "Please enter a filename."
    fi
```

Comment: $1 is the first file... $2 is the second argument, $3 is the third.

Comment: That I do know, but I just can't understand where that goes in my code.

Comment: create a loop `for i in $*; do ... done` and use `$i` instead of `$1`. Don't test if number of args is 1 anymore.  or test with `-ge`.

Comment: Don't use `$*` -- use `"$@"`. Test number of arguments with `[[ $# -gt 0 ]]`

Comment: @ignorantservant, what do you want the field separator for the "final" file to be? Due to that backslash in the `paste` command, you are using the string `" first"` as the value for the `-d` option.

Comment: If this script already work fine, then just: replace 1st  line `if [ $#...` by  `while [ $# -gt 0];do`, then last line `fi` by `shift ; done`.   This will loop over command line! (Don't forget `shift`!!)

Answer (score 1):

All those temp files are unnecessary. [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) can do all of what sed and cut can do, so this *should* be what you want (pending the output field separator question)

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then 
    echo "usage: $0 file ..."
    exit 1
fi
for file in "$@"; do
    if ! [ -f "$file" ]; then
        echo "file not found: $file"
        continue
    fi

    name="My Name"
    echo "$name"
    date

    awk -F, -v OFS=" " '
        /^id/ {next}
        {
            gsub(/-/, "")
            sub(/^ /, "", $2)
            sub(/^ /, "", $3)
            print $3, $2 ":", $1
        }
    ' "$file" > final
    cat final
done
```

Note all my double quotes: those are required.

Comment: As `final` is a file, located where script is run, overwritted on each loop, why did you create them, instead of just printing output on terminal?

Comment: Assuming that `final` needs to be written, then `tee` may be better than `cat`, as it can be writing to stdout before the file is closed.

Comment: This is mostly a good example of best practice - so, please would you write the error messages to stderr?  That would make it an excellent didactic program.  :-)